# My JavaScript isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#">
    <p>Name:<input type="text"/></p>
    <p>Password:<input type="text"/></p>
    <p><input id= "newsletter_button"type="button" value="CLICK ME"/></p>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
$(":text").focusin(function () {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
$(":text").blur(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
});
```

hello.js and index.html is in same file. I think there is some problem in jQuery.

Comment: I ran the code and don't see any issues. You haven't actually explained what the problem is. What isn't working for you?

Comment: That is a really bad choice for a title.

Comment: the focusin function is not  working i even try ran 3 different but function is not the hello.js is showing in dev tool

Comment: @PranshuShah the function worked perfectly for me. Either you have javascript disabled or you misunderstand the function. Explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: This is a dupe of many others, but finding a target will be difficult. you're binding event handlers to elements that don't exist yet. you need to wait until they exist.

Comment: @KevinB sorry mate i noob i did not get you!!

Comment: `$(":text")` selects all text inputs currently on the page. When it ran, there were no text inputs on the page yet. keyword there is "yet"

Comment: @LemuelBotha my javascript option enabled and my i am trying to achieve that is whenever i  click the any input text turn to red

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either put your hello.js at the end before `</body>` or wrap it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(":text").focusin(function () {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
$(":text").blur(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
});
});
```

What it does is executes the code once full page is loaded. Otherwise if you put it before the ":text" DOM object is loaded it will encounter DOM object not defined error.

Also you have a markup error

```
<p><input id= "newsletter_button"type="button" value="CLICK ME"/></p>
```

Put a space before type:

```
<p><input id= "newsletter_button" type="button" value="CLICK ME"/></p>
```